# Make jquery datatables load faster Nodejs backend

Tags: node.js, datatables

I am using Jquery datatables to display data to the user.

So when a user makes a request to the page in my Nodejs server:

```
router.get("/",middleware.isLoggedIn,async function (req, res) {
  try{
       let result = await rows.query(`
                    Select col1,col2,col3,col4,col5 from mytable where condition`)
        res.render("Page.ejs",{data:result.recordset})
   }
   catch(err){
      console.log(err)
   }
})
```

Now, using this data:

```
let tblAssignedJobs = $('#tblAssigned').DataTable({
"pageLength": 25,
"oLanguage": {
    "sEmptyTable":"There are no jobs assigned to you at this moment"
}
});




function populateData(assignedData) {
    let frmEditJobString = ""
    let rows = ""
    tblAssigned.clear().draw()
    for(let item of assignedData){
        frmEditJobString = 
                        `<form action="/editJobs" method="POST">
                        <input style="display:none"  name="jobNumber" value="${item.RoeseJobNumber}"> 
                        <button class="btn btn-primary">Edit Job</button></form>`
        rows = rows +  `<tr><td>${item.Number}</td>
                                    <td>${item.Type}</td>
                                    <td>${item.Name}</td>
                                    <td>${item.CustomerName}</td>
                                    <td>${item.Description}</td>
                                    <td>${item.Number}</td>
                                    <td>${item.Address}</td>
                                    <td>${frmEditString}</tr>`

    }

    tblAssigned.rows.add($(rows)).draw();

    //Remove from memory
    frmEditJobString = "" 


}
```

Now, to load 15,858 rows it is taking about 5 seconds which is not that bad but I feel like it would be much better if I could just load the first page and load other pages in the background since I am showing 25 records per page.

Or, is there a way to make requests per page, instead of loading the entire data. If someone has used Nodejs with bootstrap datatable what kind of solution did you implement?

Comment: This is quite complicated. You have to implement paging in your rest interface and query. It's a good idea to query the first page that is being displayed to the user and show it, then immediately request the rest of the data to fill up the table in the background. That way the user will see the first page of data quickly, but shortly afterwards will be able to randomly switch to any other page.

Comment: One possible way forward using DataTables and pagination: DataTables supports [server-side processing](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/). See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60801535/how-can-i-load-a-set-number-of-rows-from-a-table-on-pageload-and-only-load-furth/60804184#60804184).