# Render the mongo Collection Data in jquery datatable in less time

Tags: jquery, node.js, mongodb, datatables

**Table UI**

```
 <div class="card mt-5 mr-5 ml-5 mb-5" id="bookInfo">
      <table
        id="table_id"
        class="display table-design cell-border"
        data-page-length="10"
      >
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Author</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Cover Page</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

**Data Table Populating code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/api/v1/bookdata?page=1&limit=10000",
    dataType: "json",
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(data) {
      let tr;
      const books = data.results;
      for (let i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
        tr += "<tr>";
        tr += "<td>" + books[i].authors + "</td>";
        tr += "<td>" + books[i].title + "</td>";
        tr += "<td><img src='" + books[i].image_url + "' /></td>";
        tr += "</tr>";
      }
      $("#table_id").append(tr);
      tblFormation();
    },
    error: function(xhr) {}
  });
  function tblFormation() {
    $("#table_id").DataTable({
      searching: true,
      processing: true,
      scrollY: 700,
      deferRender: true,
      scroller: true
    });
  }
});
```

**Node JS GET API**

```
  app.get("/api/v1/bookdata", (req, res) => {
    const mydara = db.collection(BOOKDATA);
    const page = parseInt(req.query.page);
    const limit = parseInt(req.query.limit);
    const startIndex = (page - 1) * limit;
    const endIndex = page * limit;

    const results = {};

    if (endIndex < mydara.length) {
      results.next = {
        page: page + 1,
        limit: limit
      };
    }

    if (startIndex > 0) {
      results.previous = {
        page: page - 1,
        limit: limit
      };
    }

    mydara.find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
      var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      } else {
        results.results = obj.slice(startIndex, endIndex);
        res.send(results);
      }
    });
  });
```

I am able to get the data but the rendering time is way more around *1 minute* which is bad for the *UX*. I am not able to reduce the loading time in this. If possible can someone suggest the idea to reduce loading time of this data. The total data is **10000** which is coming from *mongodb collection*. **If any more snippet is required please comment here**.

Comment: Are you displaying all 10,000 documents in a single table, on a single page, all at once? Are you using some sort of pagination on the table? I suggest looking into paginated queries + table pagination.. Using `$skip` and `$limit` in your queries along with pagination should help a ton.. There are plenty of guides online that show you how to do this - [here is one of them](https://www.codementor.io/@arpitbhayani/fast-and-efficient-pagination-in-mongodb-9095flbqr)

Comment: Another possible way forward (which also leverages pagination): DataTables supports [server-side processing](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/). See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60801535/how-can-i-load-a-set-number-of-rows-from-a-table-on-pageload-and-only-load-furth/60804184#60804184).