# Is it possible to make custom pagination in jquery datatables without using ajax options?

Tags: javascript, datatables, pagination

I have a custom api that returns data with paging options. I have total count of records, current page and page offset data.

But i could not find any options that i can manipulate paging options in JQuery Datatables documentation.

Is it possible to make manual pagination with custom api. If it is not possible, i will set paging option to false and create a new pager for this.

I don't want to implement server-side pagination because i don't want to change API response. If i change the API response it will cost much more time than creating a custom pager.

Comment: You might have to manually do the paging and only let datatables output the main table area without pagination.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @coderama I think it will be the best solution to write a new pager

Comment: It depends on the specific requirements/constraints you have. But in case it is relevant, have you looked at [server-side processing](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html)? That delegates pagination control to the server. An example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60804184/12567365). If this is relevant, you would probably need to translate the pagination data structure you currently have into the structure expected by DataTables. But DataTables also uses counts and offsets.