# What is the best way to past a million records from Flask to Datatables faster?

Tags: python, flask, datatables, sqlalchemy

I'm try to pass a million records from my database which using sqlalchemy to datatables plugin.

And this is my example code.

routes.py

```
def load_sales_records():
    # query data from database
    query = Sales.query.all()

    DATA_SAMPLE = []

    # Store data records in list variable for pass to templates which have a million records
    for q in query:
        temp_dict = []
        temp_dict.append(q.id)
        temp_dict.append(q.product_name)
        temp_dict.append(q.price)
        DATA_SAMPLE.append(temp_dict)

    return jsonify({'data':DATA_SAMPLE})
```

index.html

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var table = $('#example').DataTable({
            "serverside":true,
            "deferRender": true,
            "ajax": 'load_sales_records',
   });
```

In my `load_sales_records` function.

1. query the data from database.
2. Iterate query data to convert it into list for datatables which each record contain in `DATA_SAMPLE` variable.

Problem is when implement this code with a million records it takes very long time, so are there any way to pass a million data from database to datatables faster?

Comment: `dataTables` will choke with that. Even just a few hundred records and you'll get a FOUC. You need to look into pagination to go with your AJAX

Comment: This is why DataTables has support for [server-side processing](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html). The server sends manageable subsets of data to DataTables, based on instructions sent from DataTables (next page, sorting, filtering, etc.). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60804184/12567365) for some additional notes.

Comment: @andrewjames Thank you for response, i also using server-side but are there any way to send the data from database without convert into list by using loop, as you can see my code if it looping a million record to store the data in list variable, it will also takes a very long time despite not sending to the datatables.

Comment: OK - understood. That's a different question from your original one, with various possible answers. One approach: If you are only sending 1,000 records to DataTables each time, then perhaps you should only fetch 1,000 records from the database each time. Suitable DB indexes and SQL `where` clauses should do that for you.

Comment: Why you need to display million of records on the datatable? Will user read all of these records? If they need to find something, provide them the filter for query data from database and do paging data, more filter condition given, more suitable data will be return.