# Datatable apply search on another object

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have a requirement to load 70K JSON objects in UI. If I try sending those objects to Datatable the UI is getting crashed. So what I did is I am slicing the data and showing 1000 records. I need to implement a logic that, if I search on top of that table, I need to apply search on the object which has 70K JSON object and not the object which is shown in data table. Is that possible in Datatables?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean [jQuery Datatables](https://datatables.net/) - yeah, it's possible. Based on [documentation](https://datatables.net/manual/data/):

> Server-side processing as discussed above is a special form of Ajax
> sourced data, whereby the data to be shown for each page in the
> DataTable is retrieved by an Ajax request only when that page is
> required for display to the user. This allows the power of the
> database engine on servers to be utilised for large data sets. For
> more information about server-side processing, and how it can be
> implemented, please refer to its documentation in this manual.

By sending `start` and `length` values (more details [here](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side)) you can adjust what records to show and how many of them.

Comment: I have a Javascript object upper hand in my code. can datatable perform a search on that object instead of oject that is used to render the table?

Comment: @JagadheeswaranMohan - as noted by sortas, that is the point of server-side processing. DataTables delegates responsibility  to the server for sorting, filtering, and selecting subsets of data. Take a closer look at the documentation - but in case it helps, also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60801535/how-can-i-load-a-set-number-of-rows-from-a-table-on-pageload-and-only-load-furth/60804184#60804184) for a walkthrough of server-side processing.

Comment: @JagadheeswaranMohan technically, you can control datatables by adding-removing rows through API (https://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add()), but it could be a bit annoying :)

Comment: I don't have a database. All I have is a third party application which is giving me huge JSON and instead rendering it, i would render first 100 records.If user want to search on it i would search from huge response.

Comment: In theory, you can catch page changing events (https://datatables.net/reference/event/) and, as I said before, add new rows manually (just pick it from your big array in the memory). It will be annoying a bit, but doable.

Comment: The other way is to feed all the data to datatable, but somehow slow down data processing using datatable API, so UI won't die.