# Send Parameter to Laravel DataTable controller fucntion

Tags: jquery, datatables, laravel-7

I am using Laravel [DataTable](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables). My Controller function is like below.

```
public function getProduct(Request $request,$id) {

    $product = Product::where('product_id',$id)->with('product_log')->first();
    $product_log_views = Product_log_view::where('sku',$product->sku)->with('user')->get();

    if (request()->ajax()) {
        return Datatables::of($product_log_views)
            ->addIndexColumn()
            ->addColumn('action', function($row){
                    $btn = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="edit btn btn-success btn-sm">Edit</a> <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="delete btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</a>';
                    return $btn;
            })
            ->rawColumns(['action'])
            ->make(true);
    }

    return view('welcome.product-details', ['product_log_views' => $product_log_views, 'product_log_data' => $product_log_views->toJson(),'product' => $product, 'active_menu' => 'products']);
}
```

My DataTable jQuery code is like below

```
$(function () {
    var id = window.location.pathname.split("/").pop();

    var table = $('.nk-tb-item').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: {
            url: '/product-details/'+ id,
            type: "GET",
            data: {
                "id": id
            }
        },

        columns: [
            {data: 'Dato', name: 'datetime'},
            {data: 'Bruger', name: 'user_id'},
            {data: 'På hånden', name: 'on_hand'},
            {data: 'Allokeret', name: 'allocated'},
            {data: 'Sidste ordre-id', name: 'last_orderid'},
            {
                data: 'action',
                name: 'action',
                orderable: false,
                searchable: false
            },
        ]
    });
});
```

I am getting below error

**DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7**

[image]

Comment: Server side processing expects json response not html

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl. Where should I change in my code ?

Comment: That depends on how you expect this to work and whether or not you need server side processing as defined by the plugin

Comment: You can take a look at [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60801535/how-can-i-load-a-set-number-of-rows-from-a-table-on-pageload-and-only-load-furth/60804184#60804184) for some background information about server-side processing. That may point you in the right direction, regarding the JSON which needs to be passed between the client and the server.