# Datatables AJAX POST rejected by elastic: Expected [START_OBJECT] but found [VALUE_STRING]

Tags: ajax, elasticsearch, datatables, server-side

I am trying to fix a connection to mu local elastic instance but still getting various errors when trying to used server side call.

After various tries I came to situation when getting "Expected [START_OBJECT] but found [VALUE_STRING]".

Trying to find the reason and a solution over internet but no success.

Here is my code.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var query = '{ "query" : { "match_all" : {} } }';
    console.log (query);
    query = JSON.stringify(query);
    console.log (query);
        
    $('#integrations').DataTable( {
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
      "ajax": {
                "url": "http://localhost:9200/integrations-prod/_search?size=1000&source_content_type=application/json",
                //WORKS EVEN WITH GET BUT NOT AS SERVERSIDE "url": `http://czchown5029751.prg-dc.dhl.com:9200/integrations-prod/_search?size=1000&source_content_type=application/json&source=${query}`,
                //WORKS EVEN WITH GET BUT NOT AS SERVERSIDE "url": `http://czchown5029751.prg-dc.dhl.com:9200/integrations-prod/_search?size=10000`,
                data : function ( d ) {
                return query;
            },
                "contentType": "application/json",
                //"cache": "false",
        "type": "POST",
        //"jsonp": "true",
        "dataType": "json",
        "dataSrc": "hits.hits",
            "columnDefs": [ { "defaultContent": "-", "targets": "_all" } ]
            },
            "columns": [
            { "data": "_source.name" },
            { "data": "_source.description" },
            { "data": "_source.valid" },
            { "data": "_source.status_id" },
            { "data": "_source.region_id" },
            { "data": "_source.validated_time" }
        ]
    } )
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: Not an answer, just an observation: When you use `"serverSide": true`, that means DataTables sends data to the server every time the  user performs a search, sort or paging operation. This data allows the server to respond with the correct page of results. But if you want to add your own data to be sent to the server in , `data : function ( d ) { return query; }`, then you must not overwrite the contents of `d` (which are the instructions I referred to above - use a `console.log( d )` statement to see what it contains).

Comment: Instead you can add your extra `query` data to `d`, if you want to. You can see examples in the documentation for [`ajax.data`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data). Or, maybe you deliberately want to ignore all user search/sort/paging actions?

Comment: @andrewJames, I am trying to add query content to posted payload. Of course would like to keep potential search or sorting commands.

Comment: @andrewJames, somehow it started to work but now I am getting Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries (filtered from NaN total entries) even if I will get 90 records back. Weird. Searching on net for the solution

Comment: Are you familiar with what happens when you choose to use `"serverSide": true`? You are telling DataTables that you (your server) will handle all sorting, filtering and pagination logic. DataTables will no longer do _any_ of that for you. This includes communicating the correct values to display in the `Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries (filtered from NaN total entries)` message. Take a look at the [documentation](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side) where this is described with examples.

Comment: Also, what you are now asking in your comments is different from your original question. The notes in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60804184/12567365) may help.

Comment: Understood @andrewJames, I expected that it somehow works automatically. I will parse it form elastic response.